# iOS 6/7 Delta's not working iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, ios7.1

My app is in the app store, was working fine with deltas set for ios7.  With the recent 7.1 update, these deltas seem to magically have stopped working.

Anyone know more about this issue?  Googling provided no relevant links.  This HAS to have happened to someone else.

Comment: Yes! I was just about to deploy an app that's using deltas. My tester on 7.1 pointed out the problem. Sure enough - it's only on 7.1. The deltas seem to be completely ignored even though they're still available in XCode 5.1's interface builder. I don't see anything in the release notes, either.

Comment: @Seth I've created a test project so that I can see if I'm crazy or if this is true.  It doesn't happen by default, so it must be some combination of actions that causes it.  A simple view controller with some subviews shifted seems to work ok on ios6, 7, and 7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was eating my lunch, too. In my particular case, it was an easy fix.

For me, the crux of the problem was my ignorance of the implications of a translucent navigation bars I didn't even need to use the iOS 6/7 deltas the way I was using them.

With a translucent navigation bar, the coordinate (0,0) of the parent view is the top left corner of the navigation bar. However, when the navigation bar is opaque, the parent view's coordinate (0,0) is just below the navigation bar on the far left. I was using iOS 6/7 deltas to compensate for the different navigation bar heights between the two platform versions. I was trying to use translucent navigation bars like opaque navigation bars and I didn't realize it.

My solution was to change all of my navigation bars to opaque and move the views to autolayout. This allowed my views & controls to be positioned relative to the "top" of the parent view with "top" being what I was expecting: the border of the navigation bar.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: hah.  I ended up doing the exact same.  I think I wanted to keep my options open for having a translucent navbar, but it turns out I didnt need it, and it really cost me.  Oh well!